# Find the first match for a string in text and return sample of original text

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, substr

I have a text that includes all sort of special chars and I need to find the first match for a string and then return something like this 10 chars + first match + 10 chars. In other words a sample of the text where the first match is around the middle.

Example:

```
$text = "+!This is a text with some % special chars/text and ( for a string query to match. Then !! mor&&&e and so on...chars/text.";
$stringToFind = "hars/t";
```

It should return:

```
$grabtext = "% special chars/text and ( for";
```

I made the example of a string to find that is not a complete word and has 1 special char.

Comment: have you tried using str_pos() ? It gives you the position of the first match in the string. Then you can guess the position of the first char you want to print, and the last one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/strpos)

> `strpos` — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

So if we use that function to locate the offset of the substring we can easily use something like [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) to obtain a substring of 10 characters +/- from that offset.

```
function grabText($string, $searchString) {
    if (($x = strpos($string, $searchString)) === false) {
        return; // no match found
    }
    $y = strlen($searchString) + 20;
    $x = max(0, $x - 10);
    return substr($string, $x, $y);
}

$text = "+!This is a text with some % special chars/text and ( for a string query to match. Then !! mor&&&e and so on...chars/text.";
$stringToFind = "hars/t";
echo grabText($text, $stringToFind); //  special chars/text and (
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif, great function that really does what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a regex. A `.` is any character (excluding new lines), `{}` is a character limit, or range. In this case we'll allow 10 of any character, `.{10}`.

```
~(.{10}hars/t.{10})~
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iR3pA6/1

PHP Demo: https://3v4l.org/UBKIS

Usage:

```
$text = "+!This is a text with some % special chars/text and ( for a string query to match. Then !! mor&&&e and so on...chars/text.";
$stringToFind = "hars/t";
preg_match('~.{10}' . preg_quote($stringToFind, '~') . '.{10}~', $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Note this `special c` is 10 characters, `hars/text` is your match, and `ext and (` is the additional 10 characters. Your found string or description are off.

> return something like this 10 chars + first match + 10 chars

Update, to allow upto 10 characters use:

```
$text = "+!This is a text with some % special chars/text and ( for a string query to match. Then !! mor&&&e and so on...chars/text.";
$stringToFind = "hars/t";
preg_match('~.{0,10}' . preg_quote($stringToFind, '~') . '.{0,10}~', $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iR3pA6/2

Comment: Thanks Chris... do you have any suggestion if my stringToFind is at the begining or end ( ex: !This ).. Works great if string is in the middle or at least there are enough 10 chars in each side. ( I could add 10 extra spaces at the original text at the begining and end and then trim the final result but seems somehow not very pretty ) What do you think?

Comment: You can modify the range to make the `10` an optional length. `(.{0,10}hars/t.{0,10})` Will allow 0-10 characters before the match, and/or after. Demo 2: https://regex101.com/r/iR3pA6/2 You can read more here, http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html see `Limiting Repetition`.

Comment: Thanks Chris and for the demo. I really should read more about regular expressions but my php is very limited.